# MySQL Join Improvement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble getting MySQL to return a query properly.

Here's my data:

```
id            date            value
2             2011-01-04         55.66
2             2011-03-23         22.33
2             2011-04-21          9.44
5             2010-01-04        104.55
5             2011-02-03         38.82
...              ...              ...
```

i'm trying to get a query to return:

```
select t1.id, max(t1.date), t1.value, t2.id, min(t2.date), t2.value
from tab1 as t1, tab1 as t2
where t1.id = t2.id
and t1.date <= '2011-03-31'
and t2.date >= '2011-04-01'
group by t1.id;
```

But it is taking forever (db has ~ 1mm lines).  I've tried various joins but then it seems to ignore the date < and > statements.  Basically I want each customers last purchase date and amount before 4/1/2011 and their first purchase and date on or after 4/1/2011.  Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: What's the meaning of `t1.value` and `t2.value` if you're aggregating over the `id`?

Comment: looks like `id` not unique field in `tab1` or else the query doesn't make sense

Comment: t1.value is the value of the sale on the last day pre-'4/1/2011', t2.is the value of the sale for the first day after 4/1/2011.  Each id will have a purchase pre and post 4/1/2011.

Comment: id is NOT a unique field.  each id has multiple rows.

Comment: Are your tables indexed properly?

Comment: yes they are indexed.  Note: each id has multiple dates, but each date has only ONE value.  ie id #2 has 50 dates they made purchases.  but each of those dates is different.  all purchases for a given date are already summed.

Comment: How can you have columns in your select (t1.value and t2.value) that aren't in the group by clause?

Comment: Didn't know that they had to be in the group by clause.  I'm a novice at best at SQL, thus the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is flawed, the columns t1.value and max(t1.date) do not have a relation to one and other.

You need to rewrite it as follows, if you want to know the total purchases per the date selected.

```
SELECT st1.id, st1.date, st1.total_value, st2.id, st2.date, st2.total_value
FROM (SELECT t1.id, t1.date, sum(t1.value) as total_value
      FROM tab1 t1
      WHERE t1.date <= '2011-03-31'
      GROUP BY t1.id
      HAVING t1.date = MAX(t1.date)
      ) st1
INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.id, t2.date, sum(t2.value) as total_value
           FROM tab1 t2
           WHERE t2.date > '2011-03-31'
           GROUP BY t2.id
           HAVING t2.date = MAX(t2.date)
           ) st2 
  ON (st1.id = st2.id)
```

Make sure you have an index on `id` and `date`

**Remarks**
`id` is generally understand as a shorthand for the primary key.
Having a field called `id` that does **not** a unique index, is confusing and widely considered a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM tab1 t2
INNER JOIN  
(SELECT t1.id,
MIN(CASE WHEN t1.date>='2011-04-01' THEN t1.date END) as min_date_1,
MAX(CASE WHEN t1.date<='2011-03-31' THEN t1.date END) as max_date_2
SUM(CASE WHEN t1.date>='2011-04-01' THEN t1.value END) sum_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN WHEN t1.date<='2011-03-31' THEN t1.value END) sum_2
FROM tab1 t1
GROUP BY t1.id)a ON 
(a.id = t2.id AND (t2.date = a.min_date_1 OR t2.date = a.max_date_2))
```

It should work fairly quick assuming you have index on (id, date).

**UPDATED** Sum added

Comment: You are selecting only a subset of the fields required.

Comment: This appears to work, but there are only 3 columns, how would it be written to get 6 columns, 3 for pre-date and 3 for post-date?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
      td.id
    , ta.`date` AS before_date
    , ta.value AS value_at_before_date
    , tb.`date` AS after_date
    , tb.value AS value_at_after_date
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT id
      FROM tabl
    ) AS td
  LEFT JOIN
    tabl AS ta
      ON ta.tablePK =   
        ( SELECT tablePK
          FROM tabl AS a 
          WHERE `date` < '2011-04-01'
            AND a.id = td.id
          ORDER BY `date` DESC
          LIMIT 1
        ) 
  LEFT JOIN
    tabl AS tb
      ON tb.tablePK =   
        ( SELECT tablePK
          FROM tabl AS b 
          WHERE `date` >= '2011-04-01'
            AND b.id = td.id
          ORDER BY `date` ASC
          LIMIT 1
        )
```

where `tablePK` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table (I do hope you have one).

An index on `(id, date, tablePK)` would be helpful for speed.

Answer (score 1):

**data** - query to generate some test data instead of creating a table hold test data.

**before_query** - retrieves the maximum date <= 2011-03-31 for each customer id

**after_query** - retrieves the minimum date >= 2011-04-01 for each customer id

Other than my use Oracle's dummy `dual` table (which I used to generate some test data), I believe I have only used standard SQL syntax.

You will not need to generate the data so that part of they query can be omitted. Wherever `data` is referenced in the query replace it with your `table name`.

```
with
    data as (select 2 as id, '2011-01-04' as trans_date, 55.66 as value from dual
                    union all
             select 2 as id, '2011-03-23' as trans_date, 22.33 as value from dual
                    union all
             select 2 as id, '2011-04-21' as trans_date, 9.44 as value from dual
                    union all
             select 5 as id, '2010-01-04' as trans_date, 104.55 as value from dual
                    union all
             select 5 as id, '2011-02-03' as trans_date, 38.82 as value from dual),

    before_qry as (select id, max(trans_date) as max_date from data
                   where trans_date <= '2011-03-31'
                   group by id),

    after_qry as (select id, min(trans_date) as min_date from data
                   where trans_date >= '2011-04-01'
                   group by id)

    select bq.*, bq_d.value, aq.*, aq_d.value
    from before_qry bq inner join after_qry aq on bq.id = aq.id
    inner join  data bq_d on bq.id = bq_d.id and bq.max_date = bq_d.trans_date
    inner join data aq_d on aq.id=aq_d.id and aq.min_date = aq_d.trans_date
```

For the test data shown in your question this query gives the following results

```
        ID MAX_DATE        VALUE         ID MIN_DATE        VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2 2011-03-23      22.33          2 2011-04-21       9.44
```